# Proof about functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a function, $B$, $C$ subsets of $Y$. If $B \cap C = \emptyset$, prove that $f^{-1} (B) \cap f^{-1} (C) = \emptyset$.

Approach

suppose $x\in f^{-1} (B) ∩ f^{-1} (C) \implies$ $f(x) \in B$ and $f(x) \in C $
 so $f(x) \in B \cap C$ which implies that $f(x) \in \emptyset$ , so contradiction

Comment: Does $f^c$ mean $f^{-1}$?

Comment: Other than the fact you wrote $f(x) \in A \cap B$ where you should have $f(x) \in B \cap C$, the proof is correct.

Comment: @Jingfei $^c$ is commonly used to denote the complement, which is very different than the preimage, so you should use the notation $f^{-1}$ or $f^{\leftarrow}$

Comment: You do not actually need to do a proof by contradiction, though it is perhaps easier to think of how to construct the proof that you have written by thinking that way. (Ask yourself how to repeat the above proof by supposing $B\cap C = \emptyset$ instead of $x\in f^{-1}(B)\cap f^{-1}(C)$)